# アプリ名をローカライズする方法

Tags: ios, android, monaca

Monacaを使ってiOS、Androidのアプリを開発しています。
多言語に対応したアプリのため、端末上で表示されるアプリ名を端末の言語設定によって切り分けたいのですが、やり方が分かりません。
アプリ名をローカライズする方法をご存知の方いらっしゃったら教えください。

例）
日本語設定の端末上でのアプリ名の表示：風船ゲーム
英語語設定の端末上でのアプリ名の表示：Balloon Game

Answer (score 1):

Androidについては、

[Androidアプリのローカライズ方法](https://conyac.cc/ja/business/columns/localization_guide_android)

iOSについては、
[iOS(iPhone)アプリのローカライズ方法](https://conyac.cc/ja/business/columns/localization_guide_ios)

で説明されていますので、参考にしてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。OSそれぞれのローカライズ方法は分かったのですが、monacaというプラットフォームを利用しており、そちらでのアプリ名のローカライズ方法を知りたいのです。
https://ja.monaca.io/